# Markers not showing up using geocoder and gmaps4rails

Tags: gmaps4rails, rails-geocoder

I am using geocoder gem and gmaps4rails gem. I have followed the instructions for installing both, and I am able to display a dummy map on my page, however, when I try to add in the @hash from my controller, the markers do not show. Any help would be appreciated! I am a newbie :-)

My 'Show' view:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
  handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
    markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
    handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
    handler.fitMapToBounds();
  });
</script>
```

My Trail Controller:

```
def index
    @trails = Trail.all
    @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@trails) do |trail, marker|
      marker.lat trail.latitude
      marker.lng trail.longitude
      marker.title trail.title
    end
  end

  def show
    @trail = Trail.find(params[:id])
    @posts = @trail.posts
    @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@trails) do |trail, marker|
      marker.lat trail.latitude
      marker.lng trail.longitude
      marker.title trail.title
    end
  end

  def new
    @trail = Trail.new
  end

  def create
    @trail = Trail.new(params.require(:trail).permit(:title, :state, :address, :latitude, :longitude, :body, :images))
    if @trail.save
      flash[:notice] = "Trail was saved."
      redirect_to @trail
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was an error saving the trail. Please try again."
      render :new
    end
  end
```

My Trail Model:

```
class Trail < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :posts
  mount_uploader :images, ImagesUploader

  geocoded_by :address
  after_validation :geocode
end
```

Comment: for which action does it "fail"?

Comment: It fails on the 'show' action.

Comment: Oh, I see my mistake now! '@trails' should be '@trail' for the show action. I wasn't thinking about that at all. It's working perfectly now, thank you.

Comment: :) then close your question, otherwise it spoils stats ;)